# HBase: Custom scanner to only retrieve columns by prefix

Tags: hbase

I am using a scanner to retrieve rows from HBase.  I can set which columns I want back via the addColumn() method.  However, I really need to be able to retrieve a variable number of columns that all start with the same prefix.

So, all the columns I want start with "USA", for example.  I need to retrieve all columns that start with that, such as "USA-Virginia", "USA-Hawaii", etc.  I do not want values such as "Canada-Quebec".  There are no predefined values for the full column names anywhere.  I just need all of them that start with "USA".  Is there a way to get HBase Scanners to do this?  I don't see much in the way of writing custom scanners out there.

I was looking at custom filters, but this just seems to limit the rows I get, as opposed to specifying the columns I want returned.  Thoughts?

I cannot change the structure of my data, and all of my data is under a single column family.

Thanks for any ideas.  I am running CDH3u4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is the ColumnPrefixFilter to filter keys by their columns prefix
  http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hbase/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/ColumnPrefixFilter.html

Something like this should do the trick :-

```
filter = new ColumnPrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes("USA"))
```

Comment: Turns out this was not really my problem anyway.  I had tried this, but it did not work.  The issue was really in the FilterList I was using after it.  Appreciate the quick response.

Comment: How did you resolve this? I am having a similar need.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SubstringComparator`, that might solve your problem.